# Hide status bar

Tags: iphone, xcode, statusbar, viewcontroller

I have a start page with some buttons and when pressing a button it slides to next ViewController using Navcontroller.
I want to have the status bar visible from start and for most of the different ViewControllers but for just one of them where I want the status bar hidden.
I try this and put the code in -(void)viewDidLoad in implement file.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];
```

and yes, the status bar is hidden, but when going back it is still hidden and I do not understand how I can get it to reappear. It seems to be hidden until I restart the app all together. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to make sure that the status bar is visible when you return to the other view controllers. You can possibly call `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:NO];` in each of the other view controller's `viewDidAppear` methods or another suitable place.

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint at those places to see if the code is called at all?

Comment: No it is not called when returning. I tried to put the code where you suggested or in viewDidLoad

Comment: viewDidLoad won't be called everytime the view controller will become visible again. Maybe you can post some code? It's hard to tell without seeing your code.

Comment: It is really not complicated. Take a templet like a view and an alternate view. And want to have status bar hidden in alternate view and visible when going back. And the code is like this,@implementation FlipsideViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];
    
    [super viewDidLoad];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

Comment: This works for the flipview but is still hidden in the main view. How do I get staus bar back?

Comment: This was a bad example may be because it is simple to get it back if putting the code where YES is set to NO in -done method

Comment: I got it to work also in a Nav based ViewController and added the viewWillAppear method in the main viewController. So the status bar is back when going back for that view and other views. Just the view I want to be without status bar is so.